# Java (IntelliJ) does not open file at a set path

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've just installed IntelliJ on OSX and I'm trying to write a project where I'm trying to read a text file (among other things).

In this project there's a very essential feature that I need:

It has to be able to **open, read and write a text file** at some **arbitrary given path** on the filesystem. In other words, making any changes to the working directory other than from the main source file is not an option.

I have the following code that produces the following output:

```
String musicPath = "/Users/test/Desktop/testfolder/";
    File file = new File(musicPath + "filelist.txt");
    System.out.println(file.canExecute());
    System.out.println(file.canRead());
    System.out.println(file.canWrite());
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

The output is:

```
false
true
true
/Users/test/Desktop/testfolder/
```

However, when I'm adding the line

```
FileReader filelist = new FileReader(file);
```

I'm getting a file not found exception. Needless to say, the file exists.
I've set the permissions such that anybody can read/write that file or folder but I'm still getting the same thing.

Could anybody tell me if there is a way to make the program recognise the file I have on the system? From every place this question is asked I see 3 types of replies: either check if the file exists, check the permissions or change the working directory from the project config.

Comment: try `new FileReader(musicPath + "filelist.txt");`

Comment: I have the same result with that argument

Comment: print `file.exist()`

Comment: that returns true as well